# Specify privacy when POSTing to Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to automatically post Notes on Facebook and have them be targeted to just a single member of a group.  By target I mean only a specific Facebook user should be able to read the note.

Is there a way to do this with the graph API?  I see in the old REST API there is a "privacy" parameter on the steam.publish method (see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish).  Is there an equivalent in the graph API?

Comment: I also intend to know the answer. Gosh you asked this question on August 25th.

Comment: I have seen in the link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ that we can't change the privacy setting of user ...  :(

Answer (score 7):

Here's the answer.

Just include "privacy" in the Bundle in JSONObject format, including value "SELF", "ALL_FRIENDS" OR "EVERYONE".

This is using android SDK 2.0, and 3.0 is now avaliable, But the way to use graph api is the same, left comment if you reach any problem:).

```android
public String PostWall(String Message,int Level){
    /***********************************************************
        * level 0 ==>only me
        * level 1==>friend only
        * level 2==>public
        * level >2 ==>error
    ***********************************************************/
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", Message);
    JSONObject privacy = new JSONObject();
    try {
        switch (Level){
            case 0: 
                privacy.put("value", "SELF");
                break;
            case 1: 
                privacy.put("value", "ALL_FRIENDS");
                break;
            case 2: 
                privacy.put("value", "EVERYONE");
                break;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
    }
    params.putString("privacy", privacy.toString());
    //Step 2 Request
    String resp= "";
    try {
        resp = fb.request("me/feed", params, "POST");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    try{
        resp = new JSONObject(resp).getString("id");
        if(enableLog){
            Log.d(LOGTAG,"*****POSTWALL END*****");
            Log.d(LOGTAG,"RETURN "+resp);
        }
        return resp;
    }catch(JSONException e1){
    }
}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SELF`

`php` `facebook api` example:

```
$privacy = array(
        'value' => 'SELF' //private
    );

$publish = $facebook->post('/me/videos',
        array('access_token' => $page_token,
        'title'=> $title,
        'privacy'=> $privacy,
        'source' => $facebook->videoToUpload($fn),
        'description' => $desc
        ));
```

---

> object containing the **`value`** field and optional **`friends`**, **`networks`**,
>   **`allow`** and **`deny`** fields.
>
> The **`value`** field may specify one of the following strings: **`EVERYONE`**,
>   **`ALL_FRIENDS`**, **`NETWORKS_FRIENDS`**, **`FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS`**, **`CUSTOM`** .
>
> The **`friends`** field must be specified if **`value`** is set to **`CUSTOM`** and
>   contain one of the following strings: **`EVERYONE`**, **`NETWORKS_FRIENDS`** (when
>   the object can be seen by networks and friends), **`FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS`**,
>   **`ALL_FRIENDS`**, **`SOME_FRIENDS`**, **`SELF`**, or **`NO_FRIENDS`** (when the object can be
>   seen by a network only).
>
> The **`networks`** field may contain a comma-separated list of network IDs
>   that can see the object, or 1 for all of a user's network.
>
> The **`allow`** field must be specified when the **`friends`** value is set to
>   **`SOME_FRIENDS`** and must specify a comma-separated list of user IDs and
>   friend list IDs that 'can' see the post.
>
> The **`deny`** field may be specified if the **`friends`** field is set to
>   **`SOME_FRIENDS`** and must specify a comma-separated list of user IDs and
>   friend list IDs that 'cannot' see the post.

---

Search for **privacy** on the following link to see all options:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/post

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post

There's a field called privacy which you can modify.

Hope that helps,
-Roozbeh

Comment: Couldn't understand how to change the privacy ???? the explanation in that page says " any non-default privacy setting must be intentionally chosen by the user. You may not set a custom privacy setting unless the user has proactively specified that they want this non-default setting. "

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post

does not tell how to specify privacy
in correct way

for varied option CUSTOM, FRIENDS, NETWORK_FRIENDS

Comment: you are right, it says about the return type object and all and also mentions below it that we can not change the privacy policy of user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting notes from an app, you can set default activity privacy as shown here:

[image]

It could be set when you are authenticating your own application, or in: `account settings - > applications`.