# How to put privacy parameter to Facebook live api with android

Tags: android, facebook

I'm having some troubles with Facebook live API.
I try to get a camera stream from android to use it to create a facebook livestream.
I follow the official documentation to set my request parameters, but I don't know how to set the privacy field. The [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/live_videos/) says that the privacy field is a `Privacy Parameter`, but I don't know what's the corresponding type in java for Android.

Does anyone's got a solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

As a bad english reader, the answer was just under my eyes...

[Specify privacy when POSTing to Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563538/specify-privacy-when-posting-to-facebook-graph-api)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, facebook dont want you to make mobile apps (using their live API) that stream live video using the phone camera.

Comment: Absolutely, they forbid the phone's Camera. The fact is that I don't use a phone, but a homemade camera running Android 5.